# Errors in SQL Kettle Transformation

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

I need to add some colums values to the stream final output. I am using "add constant" but it returns the error shown bellow:

> 2013/05/16 17:33:48 - Sort rows.0 - The number of binary string to
>   data type conversions done in this sort block is 0 2013/05/16 17:33:48
>   - Sort rows.0 - QuickSort algorithm has finished. 2013/05/16 17:33:48 - Table output.0 - Prepared statement : INSERT INTO ju2s6_jshopping_products (ITEMNO, `DESC`, CATEGORY, ITEMNO_1,
>   UNITPRICE, product_ean, product_quantity, unlimited,
>   product_date_added, date_modify, product_publish, product_tax_id,
>   currency_id, product_template, product_url, product_old_price,
>   product_buy_price, min_price, different_prices, product_weight, image,
>   product_manufacturer_id, product_is_add_price, average_rating,
>   reviews_count, delivery_times_id, hits, weight_volume_units,
>   basic_price_unit_id, label_id, vendor_id, access, `alias_en-GB`,
>   `short_description_en-GB`, `description_en-GB`, `meta_title_en-GB`,
>   `meta_description_en-GB`, `meta_keyword_en-GB`, `name_es-ES`,
>   `alias_es-ES`, `short_description_es-ES`, `description_es-ES`,
>   `meta_title_es-ES`, `meta_description_es-ES`, `meta_keyword_es-ES`)
>   VALUES ( ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?, 
>   ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,
>   ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?)

It seems that the values of the columns added by "add constant" are "?"

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

This looks like a problem in a Table Output step, not an Add Constants. Are you sure all of your columns are correct and are correctly matched to the input fields? Check the Table Output step field list to be sure.

If you haven't checked the 'Specify database fields' checkbox, you'll have to be sure the input columns for that step (right click and choose 'Show input fields') match the names and order of the database table fields exactly.

Note that if you did check 'Specify database fields', and you populated the grid by clicking the 'Get fields' button, what Kettle does is retrieve all the stream fields and duplicate the names for the table fields. If any of them are different you have to find and manually change the table field to the correct one.

Comment: Nice, with your answer i can solve part of the problem, but now spoon said: Data truncated for column 'product_id' at row 1

Comment: Make sure the data types from the stream and the table are assignment compatible. Kettle will not silently truncate. For example if 'product_id' is a string, you must truncate the string (with a Strings Cut) in your transform so that it fits in the column. If the MySQL table is an integer, make sure your MSSQL column is not a BIGINT. If it is, you can narrow the type with a Select Values step. Etc, etc.